# Spark workers 'KILLED exitStatus 143' when given huge resources to do simple computation

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes

Running Spark on Kubernetes, with each of 3 Spark workers given 8 cores and 8G ram, results in

```
Executor app-xxx-xx/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
```

seemingly no matter how simple the computation or what flags I pass to `spark-submit`.

For instance,

```sh
kubectl run -n redacted spark-client --rm -it --restart='Never' \
  --image docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.2.0-debian-10-r2 \
  -- run-example \
    --name my-pi-calc-example-2 \
    --master spark://spark-master-svc:7077 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 1g \
    --driver-cores 4 \
    --executor-cores 4 \
    --verbose \
    SparkPi 3
```

gives me the following logs on `spark-worker-0`:

```
21/11/15 22:07:42 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/opt/bitnami/java/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx4096M" "-Dspark.master=spark://spark-master-svc:7077" "-Dspark.driver.cores=4" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.driver.memory=4g" "-Dspark.executor.memory=4g" "-Dspark.submit.pyFiles=" "-Dspark.jars=file:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/scopt_2.12-3.7.1.jar,file:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.0.jar,file:/opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.0.jar" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "-Dspark.app.name=my-pi-calc-example-2" "-Dspark.executor.cores=4" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@xx.xx.19.190:34637" "/opt/bitnami/spark/work/driver-20211115220742-0006/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.0.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi" "3" "--verbose"
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20211115220744-0006/4 for Spark Pi
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/11/15 22:07:44 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/opt/bitnami/java/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/:/opt/bitnami/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx4096M" "-Dspark.driver.port=42013" "-Dspark.rpc.askTimeout=10s" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@spark-worker-0.spark-headless.redacted.svc.cluster.local:42013" "--executor-id" "4" "--hostname" "xx.xx.19.190" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20211115220744-0006" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@xx.xx.19.190:34637"
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20211115220744-0006/4
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20211115220744-0006/4 interrupted
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO Worker: Executor app-20211115220744-0006/4 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 4
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20211115220744-0006, execId=4)
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Application app-20211115220744-0006 removed, cleanupLocalDirs = true
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20211115220744-0006
21/11/15 22:07:48 INFO Worker: Driver driver-20211115220742-0006 exited successfully
```

I can drop, change, or modify the `run-example` or `spark-submit` flags. It seemingly has no effect, even for something as simple as `SparkPi 3`; the executors are killed and exit code 143 with very little information about why they were actually killed.

Resource constraints should not be an issue whatsoever here. This is a Kubernetes cluster of 3 AWS m5.4xlarge worker nodes, 16 vCPu and 64GiB RAM with very little else actually deployed on the. I have not set Kubernetes `spec.resources` on `limits` or `requests`. The Spark cluster is deployed as follows:

```sh
argocd app create spark \
    --repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami \
    --helm-chart spark \
    --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc \
    --insecure \
    --helm-set 'worker.replicaCount=3' \
    --dest-namespace redacted \
    --revision '5.7.9' \
    --helm-set worker.coreLimit=8 \
    --helm-set worker.memoryLimit=8G \
    --helm-set worker.daemonMemoryLimit=4G \
    --helm-set master.daemonMemoryLimit=4G

argocd app sync spark
```

This uses the [Spark Bitnami Helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/spark) and ArgoCD/Helm to deploy.

The cluster deploys just fine; I can see, for example, `Starting Spark worker xxx.xx.xx.xx:46105 with 8 cores, 8.0 GiB RAM` and that all 3 workers have joined.

What am I missing here? How can I better debug this and figure out what the resource constraint is?

---

Funny enough, I can even run SparkPi locally. If I e.g. `kubectl exec -it spark-worker-0 -- bash`:

```sh
$ ./bin/run-example SparkPi 3
...
21/11/15 22:22:09 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.0
...
21/11/15 22:22:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: reduce at SparkPi.scala:38, took 0.634538 s
Pi is roughly 3.1437838126127087
```

Then I can add two arguments to run in cluster mode, and boom, executors get killed:

```
$ ./bin/run-example \
    --master spark://spark-master-svc:7077 \
    --deploy-mode cluster SparkPi
# Executor app-20211115222530-0008/2 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
```

Comment: IIRC, 143 is an OOM error

Comment: Yes. That being the nature of my confusion. 8GB of RAM isn't enough to compute Pi to 3 digits? I have even tried jacking up RAM to 16GB per worker. Nothing seems to have an effect.

Comment: Try giving _less memory_. You dont need 4G of driver memory to compute even one digit of Pi

Comment: I have tried that too. I started with the defaults and only started using `xxx.daemonMemoryLimit=4G` once I saw "killed 143" all over the place. I have tried turning up or down seemingly every value related to memory - same result.

Comment: As I added to the question, i can run `./bin/run-example SparkPi 3` from the container shell of `spark-worker-0` - it completes no problem whatsoever. It's when I point it to `--master` with `--deploy-mode cluster` that it breaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learned a couple things here. The first is that 143 KILLED does not seem to actually be indicative of failure but rather of executors receiving a signal to shutdown once the job is finished. So, seems draconian when found in logs but is not.

What was confusing me was that I wasn't seeing any "Pi is roughly 3.1475357376786883" text on stdout/stderr. This led me to believe the computation never got that far, which was incorrect.

The issue here is what I was using `--deploy-mode cluster` when `--deploy-mode client` actually made a lot more sense in this situation. That is because I was running an ad-hoc container through `kubectl run` which was not part of the existing deployment. This fits the definition of [client mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) better, since the submission does not come from an existing Spark worker. When running in `--deploy-mode=cluster`, you'll never actually see stdout since input/output of the application are not attached to the console.

Once I changed `--deploy-mode` to `client`, I also needed to add `--conf spark.driver.host` as documented [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2883) and [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2946), for the pods to be able to resolve back to the invoking host.

```sh
kubectl run -n redacted spark-client --rm -it --restart='Never' \
  --image docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.2.0-debian-10-r2 \
  -- /bin/bash -c '
run-example \
  --name my-pi-calc-example \
  --master spark://spark-master-svc:7077 \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --conf spark.driver.host=$(hostname -i) \
  SparkPi 10'
```

Output:

```
21/11/15 23:22:16 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage finished
21/11/15 23:22:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: reduce at SparkPi.scala:38, took 2.961188 s
Pi is roughly 3.140959140959141
21/11/15 23:22:16 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4040
21/11/15 23:22:16 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
21/11/15 23:22:16 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
```

Interestingly enough this is `app-20211115232213-0024`, which in the Spark Master UI still shows each worker as KILLED 143 - reinforcing the conclusion that that is a 'normal' shutdown signal.